# Phonegap LocalFileSystem + Sencha Touch 2 + Android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I've got a Sencha Touch 2.0 application that works fine on iOS. But on Android there is a little problem with the LocalFileSystem object from PhoneGap 2.2.0. In my **index.html** i've got the following code as provided in the PhoneGap doc:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('onDeviceReady');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.name);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

</script>
```

But the "deviceready" event gets never fired. There is no output in the console. So I can't get the LocalFileSystem working. I event tried to add a function call in the onload event of the body that adds the eventListener for deviceready. The functions gets called, but again the deviceready won't be fired. Whats the correct way to get this working and call the launch function of Sencha Touch afterwards? I tried it in simulator with Android API 14, 16 and 17 and on an Galaxy Tab with Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Did you add the correct Cordova file that belongs to Android? Is it correctly added in your index.html? Does the file name Cordova-2.2.0 match with that the one you've included?

Comment: Your first tip was the correct one. I added the cordova-2.2.0.js from the iOS build in the project by mistake. Shame on me...

Comment: Glad that you've got it fixed. :)